# 2sxc Adam folder list

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, adam, dnn9

I have a problem with listing/showing Folders created within Adam's File Library?

I have dowloaded Adam 2.0 tutorial [from your site](https://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/tutorial-for-adam-2-app-for-dnn-dotnetnuke)

I can't get them listed even in downloaded template and example "Another one rides the bus". If I change template view "Adam example with groups (folders) I don't see any image at all.

I tried adding `@screenshots.Folders.Count` but I get value `0` even there are already 2 non-empty folders created in given example gallery.
For `@screenshots.Files.Count` I get `4` which is correct value for a root level.

I get no other errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if those examples are all still current. But if you check out the latest Blueimp that may help. See https://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/blueimp-gallery-slider-4-0-with-koi-bootstrap-3-and-4.

Comment: Blueimp is not providing solution to my question, as it doesn't utilise `data.Folders` methods as in that other example.
My goal is to use adam file picker both for files and folders, to create directory structure that I can traverse and use/list like documents tree with folders and subfolders.

Comment: So basically it should work - but I don't know where you're stuck. Maybe you can look at some code which browses this data for the API (used to create the GUI) to see what's missing. Maybe you just need a "/" or something... https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/blob/master/Sxc%20WebApi/Adam/AdamController.cs